# How to render particle (or in general physics) System in network renderer

Tags: rendering, particles, physics, baking, network

I have a problem using the "network renderer" of Blender 3D. (Using blender 2.78b on every machine, clients, slaves and master) I have an explosion modifier on an object using particles which move a bit "random".

So the problem seems to be that every Slave of the network render is generating its own "random"nes so putting the rendered animation together after, the frames don't fit to the frames rendered by another slave because this one maybe had another random particle system ..

I actually thought all clients will receive the completely baked physics from the client machine?